# Copy object instance and insert to DB using peewee creates duplicate ID

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I have an instance of an object (with many attributes) which I want to duplicate.
I copy it using deepcopy() then modify couple of attributes.

Then I save my new object to the database using Python / PeeWee save() but the save() actually updates the original object (I assume it is because that the id was copied from the original object).

(btw no primary key is defined in the object model)

How do I force save the new object? can I change its id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that I can set the id to None (obj.id = None) which will create a new record when performing save().

Comment: I get: peewee.OperationalError: no such column: id. Are you working directly on the deepcopy of the row? I have `child_row = copy.deepcopy(Table.get(Table.x="x"))`and the `child_row.id=None` does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Set the id to None (obj.id = None) resolves if you are using sqlite, otherwise use:

```
data = obj.__dict__['_data']
data.pop('id')
obj.insert(data).execute()
```